# Rails splitting active record result into arrays/hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Lets say i have an Activerecord result suchlike:

```
order.order_numbers
```

which returns an `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`

```
=> [#<OrderNumber id: 53425, Order_number: "01100", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:20:36">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53426, Order_number: "04503", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil,  updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53427, Order_number: "011004", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 2, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53428, Order_number: "004505", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53429, Order_number: "4506", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 2, comment: nil,  updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53430, Order_number: "4507", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">]
```

Notice the `Order_number_status_id`, where 1 means **open** and 2 means **closed**.

If i wanted to split this based on the ‘**closed**’ status and output the results into separate arrays, how could it be done? I only want to put the Open orders into their own array but start a new array every time it moves from a closed number to an open number.

In the example above, the result would be

- Array_1 would contain ids 53425 and 53426
- Array_2 would contain id53428
- Array_3 would contain id 53430

So it would split it up into 3 distinct hashes or arrays which would contains only open order numbers,  which would all be in a single array.

```
[[#<OrderNumber id: 53425, Order_number: "01100", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:20:36">,
 #<OrderNumber id: 53426, Order_number: "04503", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil,  updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">,], [<OrderNumber id: 53428, Order_number: "004505", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">], [<OrderNumber id: 53430, Order_number: "4507", Order_number_id: 5391, Order_number_status_id: 1, comment: nil, updated_at: "2016-11-18 16:19:49">]]
```

I’m open to suggestions as to the output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the standard method [Enumerable#chunk](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/chunk).

You can do something like:

```
order.order_numbers.chunk { |o_num| o_num.Order_number_status_id == 1 }.each{|a, b| p b}
```

Save the result in a new array to delete unnecessary pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just .split? [Array#Split](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/split)

```
order.order_numbers.split{|o| o.Order_number_status_id == 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by)

it's best suitable for you situation